# Executar função no PHP para inserir dados no DB diariamente em horário específico

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, data

Estou criando um "módulo" do meu sistema e tenho agora que criar uma função que, quando chegar no horário que está no banco de dados, execute um `insert`. Por exemplo, se na tabela estiver o horário `22:00`, às 22h00 todos os dias ele executará o `insert`.

O problema é que as vezes pode acontecer um atraso ou algo do tipo e o horário atual ser `22h01`, e como está no banco `22h00` então não irá executar o insert.

Estava pensando em colocar um intervalo. Se, por exemplo, no banco estiver `22:00` ele coloca o intervalo de 1 hora, então se for 22:00 até 23:00 ele executa o insert. Não tenho noção de como fazer, alguém consegue me ajudar com esse código PHP?

OBS: irei colocar um CRON também para ajudar.

Comment: Se os dados a serem inseridos não dependerem do PHP, pode usar o Event Scheduler do MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Este é um caminho bem simples, mas totalmente funcional para este tipo de problema:

- crie um campo `proximaexecucao` na tabela de agenda do seu DB

No PHP você vai usar o seguinte algoritmo:

- se a data/hora atual maior ou igual a `proximaexecucao`:

  - faça as operações agendadas que deseja
  - reagende o `proximaexecução` para:

    - o dia seguinte, se quiser que atrasados sejam executados uma vez só

      **OU**
    - um dia a mais do `proximaexecução` atual, se quiser que TODOS os atrasados sejam executados.
- se a data/hora atual for menor que `proximaexecucao`

  - retorna sem fazer nada

Desta forma, você terá a execução funcionando sem o risco de dupla-execução, e sem depender de comparações de minutos, ou da disponibilidade de um CRON com intervalo muito curto de tempo.

Esta solução pode ser aplicada para inúmeros agendamentos diferentes, com intervalos diferentes, desde que cada um deles tenha um campo `proximaexecucao`.

E de "brinde", tem a vantagem de poder mudar os agendamentos remotamente sem mexer na *crontab* da máquina, basta ajustar no DB. Se puser, por exemplo, uma chamada via *cron* de 5 em 5 minutos, pode agendar uma diversidade de eventos diferentes para acontecerem durante o dia, em vários horários, todos sendo executados pelo mesmo PHP.

Comment: Sua resposta abriu minha mente pra fazer o que eu preciso, valeu!

Comment: @AlissonAcioli só nao detalhei mais por falta de parâmetros, mas acho que você pegou a idéia. O bonito dela é que não tem problemas de precisão de minutos, se o cron parar por horas, continua funcionando. O segredo é que uma vez executada, ela cria uma condição que não é ambígua.

Answer (score 2):

A lógica seria algo como isso

```
<?php

$agendamento = 22; // Não vou usar minutos aqui
$horaAtual   = ; // Obtenha a hora via JS

if ( ( $agendamento >= $horaAtual ) || ( $agendamento <= $horaAtual) ) {

    # Execute alguma coisa
}
else
{
    # Ainda não é hora
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tarefas cron, ou Cron job, tem na hospedagem normalmente, só pedir informação no suporte, quando aprender, instala no teu pc/note, o windows é as tarefas comuns, e o linux é o cron se não me engano o nome.

Ai voce manda executar um script.php de tanto em tanto tempo verifica alguma coisa e executa o que tu quer.

Eu usei para o meu jogo de turnos, a cada 20 minutos trocava o turno, então executava o motor.php

Answer (score 0):

> Para usuários linux (ubuntu 18.04, versão testada)

**Vamos para um exemplo prático e real:**

**1º Passo) Vamos criar uma tabela denominada **logs** no seu banco de dados.**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**2º Passo) Vamos criar o algoritmo em um arquivo PHP que faz a inserção.**
Na pasta do xamp ou wamp ou na pasta que seus códigos html estão, crie uma pasta denominada *cron*, dentro dela crie um arquivo denominado test.php, dentro desse arquivo (test.php), insira este código:

```php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "minhasenha_aqui";
$dbname ="meubancodedados_aqui";
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO logs (description, date)VALUES ('Demo CRON','2021-09-01 19:09:00')";
  // use exec() because no results are returned
  $conn->exec($sql);
  echo "New record created successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

**3º Passo)
Para o exemplo, usuremos o utilitário de software: `curl`.

instale-o usando este comando: `sudo apt install curl`.**

**4º Passo) Vamos manipular o utilitário de software cron**.
Primeiro, veja se ele está instalado, use este comando: `crontab -e`, normalmente, vai pedir para você editar o arquivo cron.

Digite este comando: 
* * * * * curl http://localhost/cron/test.php

Pressione ctrl+x e salve o arquivo.

Prontinho! Agora, todos os minutos, todas a horas, todos dias, todas as semanas e todos o meses, o arquivo http://localhost/cron/test.php será executado, inserindo a informação que fizemos no passo 2.