# Como converter uma data em uma expressão cron?

Tags: php, javascript, cron, datapicker

Estou a desenvolver uma aplição em PHP e Javascript pra agendar algumas tarefas.

O usuario terá a possibilidade de configurar a partir de uma interface gráfica a data da execução da tarefa (com o **datapicker** por exemplo).

Gostaria de récuperar esses dados ( ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto e segundos ) e converte-los em expressões **cron**.

Existe uma técnica ou  **framework** pra isso ?

Comment: já tem a descrição toda dos campos do cron no site, se ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124518/70 - O ideal seria é uma tarefa no cron que consultasse um DB pra ver o que rodar, em vez de vc mexer no cron pelo PHP

Comment: Descrevo essa técnica aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105885/70

Comment: @Bacco acho correto a sua ideia... e como o cron iria verificar as minhas tabelas ?

Comment: O cron não verificaria suas tabelas, o cron chamaria um a aplicação sua que verificaria e executaria o que fosse necessário. Exemplo: o cron chama um "php executa.php" de 5 em 5 min, e esse PHP verificaria o DB e executaria tudo que fosse necessário. O PHP rodando pelo shell é muito mais versátil do que acessado por página, pois vc pode usar sem timeout, e como outro usuário diferente do usado no servidor de página.

Comment: @Bacco imagine que o usuario configurou uma tarefa pra uma data **x**, a minha aplicação irá armazenar esses dados na minha base. A questão é : como o **cron** terá ecesso a minha BD ? e se for pra chamar um script que verifique, em que momento isso sera feito ?

Comment: O cron chama seu script constantemente. Se não tiver nada pra fazer, seu script encerra. se tiver algo pra fazer, seu script faz, e encerra

Comment: @Bacco percebi ... vou testar, parece-me logico e digno de crédito a sua ideia !

Comment: A precisão necessária é que vai determinar o que vc vai por no Cron. Se forem tarefas que podem ser feitas apenas com hora redonda, vc pode chamar o PHP de 1 em 1 hora só, por exemplo, ou um pouco menos (15 em 15 min) para o caso de ao reiniciar o servidor ou parar o serviço por algum motivo, não demorar demais para recuperar o atraso. o Cron sempre vai estar chamando o PHP, e o PHP simplesmente verifica e encerra enquanto não der hora de coisa agendada.

Comment: @Bacco se eu chamar o meu script todos segundos , teria um impacto negativo sobre a performance do meu servidor ?

Comment: Mas vc tem tarefas que precisam dessa precisão? No caso, todo segundo é besteira usar cron. Nem é pra isso o Cron, pra falar a verdade. O mínimo é 1 minuto. Melhor deixar um PHP rodando em loop infinito então, pelo shell (nunca pelo Apache etc), com um sleep() de 1 segundo. O sleep é importante para não ficar ocupando CPU. O que tem que ver é que se algo agendado precisa de precisão de 1 segundo, é sinal de que talvez a aplicação mereça ser repensada em alguma etapa.; Mesmo uma agenda de compromissos por SMS, por exemplo, seria mais do que suficiente precisao de 1 minuto.

Comment: E pq vc vai deixar ele configurar com esse nível de detalhamento? É algo que ele tenha que fazer com essa precisão? Senão bastaria escolher data e hora sem segundos, por exemplo. Eu mesmo tenho uma aplicação que o agendamento dos minutos é um dropdown com 0 / 5 / 10 ... só de 5 em 5 min, pq é pra compromissos. Não é um despertador :)  mas é claro que vc precisa ver o uso real da aplicação, como eu não sei os detalhes, qq coisa que eu disser é besteira.

Comment: @Bacco imagine que o usuario configurou : Receber alerta na data seguinte : **2016-11-29 12:01:25**. Se surgir um atraso o usuario nunca receberia a alerta nem que se for de 1segundo. Portanto ha necessidade de verificar todo momento.

Comment: Então vc não leu meu post. Você não vai fazer comparação =, vai fazer comparação >=

Comment: @Bacco vou dar uma olhada e organizar-me melhor, e assim que puder voltarei !

Comment: Se for nesse raciocínio seu, mesmo olhando a todo segundo, nao vai poder nunca reiniciar o servidor, senão perde compromisso. Todo agendamento pressupõe verificar se a data é maior ou igual, e ao executar, marcar como executado. Assim, mesmo que o serviço saia do ar por meia hora, quando voltar executa tudo.

Comment: A idéia é que vc tenha uma tabela com agendamento, e um campo indicando se foi executado. Se a data/hora atual for igual OU MAIOR a do agendamento, e ele não está executado, precisa executar. `SELECT campos FROM agendamentos WHERE executado = 0 AND current_timestamp >= agendamento`

Comment: Exatamente ... Parece-me bastante lógico, testarei!